# Parallel.For vs Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a bunch of methods that are exclusive to each other and as such can run in parallel. Is there a good way of doing this? So far I have the below two implementations, but I am not so sure if I should go with one or the other.

Using [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.For(0, 2, i =>
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            SomeMethod1();
            break;
        case 1:
            SomeMethod2();
            break;
    }
});
```

Using [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => { SomeMethod1(); },
    () => { SomeMethod2(); }
);
```

Which of these is best performance wise? Or is there another way that will work better?

Comment: Use the most readable: `Parallel.Invoke( SomeMethod1, SomeMethod2);` No need to wrap the methods in a lambda.

Comment: @Henrik If the method is `var foo = bar();` I still have to wrap them in the lambda though don't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the performance shouldn't be the issue here. It's all about readable/maintainable code.

- The first one; I think it's bad practice to put a switch in a `Parallel.For`. It's confusing and with large switches, it will be unreadable/unmaintainable
- The second one; Thats better, you might store the actions into a `List<Action>` first.

*Like Henrik already said: `Parallel.Invoke(SomeMethod1, SomeMethod2);` is (also for me) best readable in this case. (In this case it works, because there aren't parameters/return values)*

---

But as reaction on your question; executing a switch/case each invocation, will generating some extra overhead.